# Is there any vue3 datepicker with quarters?

Tags: datepicker, vuejs3

I'm using vue3 and I need datepicker that supports selecting either single quarter or a range of quarters besides regular dates.

I can't find anything on internet except the one from Ant Design Vue but it's not working correctly in some parts. Also, the structure of the datepicker is not very well done and I have a problem selecting some parts with cypress tests.